# rails resource deep nesting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have read some articles, and i know, that it's bad to inherit more than 2 level deep resources, but let's forget now about it.

let's imagine, i have such model:

```
 car_brand
   car_model
     car_type
```

in route i could write something like this:

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :car_brands  do
          resources :car_models  do
            resources :car_types
          end
        end
end
```

but i didn't find any good article, how to generate my controller's and view, with such schema,

1. what i need to write in controller class header, something like: class

   Admin::CarBrands::CarModelsController < ApplicationController

or what? I need to clear understand this moment, each sub-model view must be in subfolder view, or how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> what i need to write in controller class header, something like: class
> Admin::CarBrands::CarModelsController < ApplicationController
> ```

Partly yes and partly no.  Yes, in that you've namespaced routes i.e. within `namespace :admin` and No, because nested resources do not mean namespaced Controllers as `CarBrands::CarModelsController`.

Since all `resources` are within the namespace `admin`, you'd generate all the controllers as follows:

```
rails g controller admin/car_brands
rails g controller admin/car_models
rails g controller admin/car_types
```

Executing each command above would place a controller class and view directory and other test specific files in their corresponding directories.  Your question is more towards controllers and views so the directories of concerns are:

```
- app/controllers/admin/
- app/views/admin/car_brands/
- app/views/admin/car_models/
- app/views/admin/car_types/
```

Your controller declaration for `CarBrandsController` would then look like:

```
class Admin::CarBrandsController < ApplicationController
  ...
end
```

With these setup, it's now up to you how you want to manage each controller as a resource.  If you nest your `car_types` within `car_models` then that the methods in `car_models` controller will also be expecting `car_type_id` in parameter.  If you don't nest `car_types` resource then the resource is a standalone resource on it's own and does not have dependencies on any other resources.

Comment: i done so, i didn't want to create new question and will ask here, what is the diference, when after select object's in db (controller) in view i do @something.each do |c|    c.id   and c[:id] ?

Comment: @ValdisAzamaris, it depends on the type of the object.  If `c` is an instance of a model then you access it with `c.id`, it it's an array or hash with `symbol` as key then you access it with `c[:id]`.  I presume `c` is an instance of of one of your models, so try `c.id`.

Answer (score 2):

`Admin::CarTypesController < ApplicationController` in `controllers/admin` folder as `car_types_controller.rb`

Run `rake routes` and take a look at this line, for example:

```
/admin/car_brands/:car_brand_id/car_models/:car_model_id/car_types(.:format)
```

This is the uri pattern that will map `Admin::CarTypesController#index` metod. In `params` hash, you will find `:car_brand_id` and `:car_model_id`.